# Error with ReactiveForms when compiling dynamic template in angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, jit

I have a code that compiles dynamic templates in angular.
This code recently worked fine in angular 11, aot mode.
Now after upgrading to angular 15 It no longer work, but shows the template without angular bindings.
Below is my code, note that in order to make it more readable the dynamic html template is hard-coded.

```
import { COMPILER_OPTIONS, Compiler, CompilerFactory, Component, Input, ModuleWithComponentFactories, NgModule, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, inject, ɵcompileComponent } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, NgFor, NgIf } from '@angular/common';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormControlDirective, FormControlName, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective, FormsModule, NgModel, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { JitCompilerFactory } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  template: '<div #container> </div>'
})

export class TestComponent {

  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
  componentRef: any;

  constructor(private compiler: Compiler) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.addDynamicTemplate();
  }

  addDynamicTemplate() {
    const comp = createComponent();
    const module = createModule(comp)
    this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(module).then((factories: ModuleWithComponentFactories<any>) => {
      const factory = factories.componentFactories.find(component => component.componentType === comp);
      this.componentRef ? this.container?.remove(0) : "";
      this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(factory);
      this.componentRef.hostView.detectChanges();

    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
}

function createComponent() {
  const templateComponent = Component({
    template: `
    <div *ngIf="display">an example for ngIf</div>
    <span *ngFor='let i of arr'>{{i}}</span>
    <div  [formGroup]="myGroup">
         {{myGroup.controls['firstName'].value}}
         <input name="firstName" formControlName="firstName"/>
    </div>
    `,
    // styles: [this.styleForm]
  })(class {
    display = true;
    arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    myGroup: FormGroup;
    constructor() {
      this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
        firstName: new FormControl('your name')
      });
    }
  });
  return templateComponent;
}
function createModule(component: any) {
  const templateModule = NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
    jit: true,
    declarations: [component],

    providers: [
      { provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: { useJit: true }, multi: true },
      { provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS] },
      { provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory] }
    ]
  })(class { });
  return templateModule;
}

export function createCompiler(compilerFactory: CompilerFactory) {
  return compilerFactory.createCompiler();
}
```

I get:

> Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.
> and
> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'span'.

I added the [ngif](/questions/tagged/ngif) and the [ngfor](/questions/tagged/ngfor) to the imports of the dynamic module:

`imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgIf, NgFor ],`

now the [ngfor](/questions/tagged/ngfor) and [ngif](/questions/tagged/ngif) work fine, but there is another error :

> Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

For this I added the [formgroupdirective](/questions/tagged/formgroupdirective) and the [formcontrolname](/questions/tagged/formcontrolname) to the declarations of the dynamic module:

> `declarations: [component, FormGroupDirective, FormControlName]`

And the dynamicModule now looks like this:

```
const templateModule = NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, NgIf, NgFor],
    jit: true,
    declarations: [component, NgModel, FormGroupDirective, FormControlName,
    ],
```

now '[formgroup](/questions/tagged/formgroup)' is fine, but the [reactiveform](/questions/tagged/reactiveform) doesn't work and shows error:

> Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'firstName'

I assume that I am missing a declaration or an import item like I added for the ngFor/ngIf/FormGroup, but I don't know which one to add in order to make the formControlName work well in a formGroup, or maybe the solution is not by adding any declaration/imports but something else?

Thanks in advance!